# setting nested object in state - React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Here is my code:

React JS  code:

```
class Item extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            product: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "Name",
                    price: "Quantity",

                    productIngredient: {
                        id: 0,
                        name: "Ingredient Name",
                        unit: "Unit(s)",
                        quantity: "Quantity",
                    },
                                        
                },
            ],  
        };
    }
}

export default Item;
```

**My Question:**

In React, I want to setState, how to set the **productIngredient** object which is in the state ?
My basic question is how to set the state for a nested object in React ?

Comment: What does the Java backend have to do with setting state in react?

Answer (score 0):

I do it usually with something like:

```
setProductIngredient = ( productIngredient, ix ) => {
  const { product } = this.state
  product[ ix ].productIngredient = productIngredient
  this.setState( { product } )
}
```

If you don't have an index, you can use find- or indexOf- methods to get the correct array element.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, if you want to fetch and populate your state with your api call, you need to use componentdidmount() [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount](http://doc%20here).

I recommend you to use the latest React version with the hooks (it's easier to use). If you use hooks, you have to use a useEffect() function in order to make your api call. Inside this function, you can populate your useState hook. [Doc here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Here is a full example with api call inside a useEffect(). [Example here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-call-web-apis-with-the-useeffect-hook-in-react).